# Avanced Entity Framework Query Example

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

this my sql command.

```
    select c.nombrecompleto fullname,c.direccion street ,c.telefono phonenumber,
c.limitecredito creditlimit,sum(vd.preciofinal) balance , case when max(a.fechacreacion) is null then '' else max(a.fechacreacion) end
lastpay 
,
case when u.nombre is null then '' else u.nombre  end paidTo
from cliente c 
inner join venta v on c.idcliente=v.idcliente 
inner join ventadetalle vd on v.idventa=vd.idventa
inner join prestamo p on p.idventa=v.idventa
left join abono a on c.idcliente=a.idcliente
left join usuario u on a.creadopor=u.idusuario
where 
c.estatus=1 and
v.estatus=1 and
vd.estatus=1 and
p.estatus=1 and
(a.estatus is null or a.estatus=1)
and (u.estatus=1 or u.estatus is null)
group by c.nombrecompleto,c.direccion,c.telefono,c.limitecredito
,u.nombre
having sum(vd.preciofinal)>0
```

i tried converted it to entity framework but i could not. 
this i got (i did not finish)

```
     from c   in Clientes
join v   in Ventas on c.Idcliente equals v.Idcliente
join vd  in Ventadetalles on v.Idventa equals vd.Idventa
join p   in Prestamos on v.Idventa equals p.Idventa 
join a   in Abonos on c.Idcliente equals a.Idcliente into al
from a in al.DefaultIfEmpty() 
join u   in Usuarios on a.Creadopor equals u.Idusuario into ul
from u in ul.DefaultIfEmpty() 
where 
c.Estatus==1 &&
v.Estatus==1 &&
vd.Estatus==1 &&
p.Estatus==1 &&
(a.Estatus==1 || a.Estatus== null) &&
(u.Estatus==1 || u.Estatus== null) 

group new{c.Idcliente,vd,a} by new { c.Nombrecompleto, c.Direccion, c.Telefono, c.Limitecredito, 
usuarionombre=((u.Nombre!=null)?u.Nombre:u.Nombre)  

}
```

Comment: So what happens with the entity framework code that shouldn't be happening?

Comment: no, problem is i dont know how to tranlate the sql command to entity framework query

Comment: If you're using entity-framework, shouldn't there be foreign keys that let you reach down into the connected tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure but i believe i have got

```
from c   in Clientes
join v   in Ventas on c.Idcliente equals v.Idcliente
join vd  in Ventadetalles on v.Idventa equals vd.Idventa
join p   in Prestamos on v.Idventa equals p.Idventa 
join a   in Abonos on c.Idcliente equals a.Idcliente into al /*this line*/
from a in al.DefaultIfEmpty() /*and this is for to do left outer join or left join*/
join u   in Usuarios on a.Creadopor equals u.Idusuario into ul 
from u in ul.DefaultIfEmpty() /*so you see here other left join*/
where 
c.Estatus==1 &&
v.Estatus==1 &&
vd.Estatus==1 &&
p.Estatus==1 &&
(a.Estatus==1 || a.Estatus== null) &&
(u.Estatus==1 || u.Estatus== null) /*this is for to do (a.estatus is null or a.estatus=1)*/

group new
{
vd.Preciofinal,a.Fechacreacion /*these are the max or sum or min columns */} 
by new {c.Idcliente, c.Nombrecompleto, c.Direccion, c.Telefono, c.Limitecredito, 
    usuarionombre=((u.Nombre!=null)?u.Nombre:u.Nombre/*the group by part in a normal sql command */
)  
    }
    into agrupacion /*inside a new table */
    where agrupacion.Sum(x=> x.Preciofinal)>0 /*this would be a having sum in a normal sql command */
    select new {
/*my columns i needs only and the sum and max*/
agrupacion.Key.Idcliente,agrupacion.Key.Nombrecompleto,agrupacion.Key.Direccion,agrupacion.Key.Telefono,
    agrupacion.Key.Limitecredito,agrupacion.Key.usuarionombre, saldo=agrupacion.Sum(x=> x.Preciofinal)
    ,ultimopago=((agrupacion.Max(x=> x.Fechacreacion)!=null)?agrupacion.Max(x=> x.Fechacreacion):DateTime.Now /*ultimopago would be a case when max(fechacreacion )is null then getdate() else max(fechaultimopago)* end as ultimopago/)
    }
```

i hope this could help to other